# Scrollviewer in Metro app - scroll by touch and handle other gesture

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, scrollviewer, gestures

I have page with Grid and Scrollviewer:

```
<Grid x:name="mainGrid">
  ...
  <ScrollViewer Name="mainScroller" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled">
    ...
  </ScrollViewer>
  ...
</Grid>
```

I want make gesture handling for vertical touch move (move up with finger), but I want preserve scrolling mainScroller content by horizontal touch move too.

I tried add for mainGrid ManipulationCompleted="Grid_ManipulationCompleted":

```
private void Grid_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Cumulative.Translation.Y < -50 && e.Velocities.Linear.Y<1000)
  {
    ...make some action...
  }
}
```

Final effect is that, if I use ManipulationMode="TranslateY" for mainGrid, then vertical touch move works, but horizontal scrolling not, and when I not use it, horizontal scrolling works, but vertical touch move not. Is it possible to make both this features functional?
Sorry for my English.

Comment: why don't you set ManipulationMode to 'All'..

Comment: I tried, but it's the same. If I add ManipulationMode on mainGrid only, I can scroll, but manipulation event is raised only out of scrollViewer. If I add ManipulationMode on mainScroller or its children elements, then I can't scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to understand your scenario, but in general you should not create new gestures that could potentially conflict with built-in gestures, like you are proposing.

John Wiese
Microsoft - Sr. Technical Evangelist
jwiese@microsoft.com
@johnwiese